# Warning messages: number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Tags: r, loops, mean, sampling

I need help with this problem. It occurs when i am running a loop for my estimator.And can anyone tell me is this problem affecting my results?

#Sample selection for Transformed data##

> `s<-sample(1:50,2,replace = FALSE,prob = NULL)
> s;data$Wy[s]
> s<-sample(1:50,2,replace = FALSE,prob = NULL)
> s;data$Wx[s]``

```
##loop for ratio estimator##
>`for(i in 1:10) 
{
  s[i]<-sample(1:50,2,replace=FALSE, prob = NULL)
  wr[i]<-  mean(data$Wy[s])/mean(data$Wx[s])  
  muwr[i]<-wr[i]*muwx                     ##ratio type mean estimator##
}`
```

##output Warning messages##

```
`1: In s[i] <- sample(1:50, 2, replace = FALSE, prob = NULL) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
2: In s[i] <- sample(1:50, 2, replace = FALSE, prob = NULL) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
3: In s[i] <- sample(1:50, 2, replace = FALSE, prob = NULL) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
4: In s[i] <- sample(1:50, 2, replace = FALSE, prob = NULL) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
5: In s[i] <- sample(1:50, 2, replace = FALSE, prob = NULL) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
6: In s[i] <- sample(1:50, 2, replace = FALSE, prob = NULL) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
7: In s[i] <- sample(1:50, 2, replace = FALSE, prob = NULL) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
8: In s[i] <- sample(1:50, 2, replace = FALSE, prob = NULL) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
9: In s[i] <- sample(1:50, 2, replace = FALSE, prob = NULL) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
10: In s[i] <- sample(1:50, 2, replace = FALSE, prob = NULL) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
> muwr
 [1] 1155.006 1155.021 1154.958 1154.875 1154.774 1154.875 1155.021 1155.021 1155.021
[10] 1155.006
> mean(muwr);var(muwr)
[1] 1154.958
[1] 0.007579488`
```

Comment: This is not reproducible. Crucially, it does not include the definition of `s`, which has to appear before the loop.

Comment: @ChrisHaug this not the complete code and i defined s in my code before using it in the loop. If you can suggest any solution i can share full code with you.

Comment: @ChrisHaug i added the sample statement which is used before the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

s[i] <- sample(1:50, 2, replace=FALSE, prob = NULL)
In the above statmentmen what i was doing wrong is that i was using s[i] instead of s, this problem was causing warning message and also affecting the sample selection command.

Answer (score 0):

> s[i] <- sample(1:50, 2, replace=FALSE, prob = NULL)

`sample(1:50, 2, ...)` will return a vector of length 2. I guess `s` is a numeric vector and you are trying to put in position `i` not one but two elements hence the warning you see at each iteration. Perhaps you want `sample(1:50, 1, ...)`?

I don't know how the final results are going to be affected but I suggest you fix the inconsistency anyway.

Comment: In this command s[i] <- sample(1:50, 2, replace=FALSE, prob = NULL) i am suggesting to select a serial value that ranges from 1 to 50. The 2 here is sample size, replace... is used to avoid repetition of values and prob.. will assign equal chance of selection.

Comment: the command was working fine but today it suddenly giving the warnings.

Comment: i am using this s[i] command in 'for loop' to store defined sample size values.